# loading array values in custom order using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Loading array initial value/1st value to end of the array; using ng-repeat and orderby filter;

[Array using ng-repeat](http://plnkr.co/edit/nI8d4yclhmKKWmIRUjA3?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script.js file, create a sort function.

```
$scope.sort = function(value){
var index = $scope.myvar.indexOf(value);
  if(index === 0){
     return $scope.myvar.length;
  }
  return index;
}
```

In your index.html file, change your ng-repeat attribute to look like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="v in myvar|orderBy:sort:false">{{v}}</li>
```

A couple of things to note.  This assumes that you want the natural order of the array except that you want the first element to go to the end.  If you want a different order you will need to alter the sort function.  See the [AngularJS orderBy function documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) for more details.

Also, the indexOf function of an array is not well supported across all browsers (IE does not implement it if I am not mistaken).  You will need to create it yourself if it doesn't already exist.  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for help on this topic.

Click [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PfWW26eQtFoCreOS6on4?p=preview) to see a working plunker version.